# How can I get japanese character correctly shown in oracle database

Tags: php, oracle, character-encoding

I know oracle database have two character set ：
`NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` and `NLS_CHARACTERSET`.

I have set them as:

```
NLS_CHARACTERSET           WE8MSWIN1252
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET     UTF8
```

when I create the database.

Also I create my table use `NVARCHAR` not `VARCHAR`,so it is supposed to be saved use `UTF8` :

```
ID          NUMBER      
EMAIL       NVARCHAR2(255)  
USER_NAME   NVARCHAR2(255)      
POST_AT     DATE
CONTENTS    NVARCHAR2(255)
```

However I can not get the right outputs. When I insert rows containing japanese characters, it just give out like "???" when I check it at terminal.

I don't know why it is not working. Does any one know a method to solve this problem?

Also, if I don't care how it is saved in database, just want to get the right output after taking out from database, is there any method to decode it correctly? (I have tried several method to convert encoding but not working)

I use PHP's OCI8 to access the database. 
the version of oracle database is oracle 11gR2 for linux.x64

Comment: What encoding is your terminal using? Can it display the characters at all, eg `echo "オーバーフロー岩スタック"`

Comment: of course my terminal can display japanese characters. I use Virtual machine with a CentOS OS to run oracle database and I access it using my MAC. It have all the japanese environment.

Comment: the virtual machine could display japanese characters too.

Comment: Have you checked whether you can insert and select japanase text via sqlplus?

Comment: I tried. All Japanese characters turned to be like "????". actually I don't care how it is saved in database because I won't be looking at database all the time. the problem is, php can not decode/encode(?) them correctly.

Comment: Please read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120723/how-to-insert-indian-rupee-symbol-in-oracle-11g/18198563#18198563), it contain some useful information about dealing with national character sets. Also check [`NLS_LANG` character set](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9724946/232279) setting on your client machine.

Comment: Also for `OCI` interface you may try [`ORA_NCHAR_LITERAL_REPLACE` environment variable](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch7progrunicode.htm#CACHHIFE).

Comment: And finally, correct answer for `PHP` may be "You need to [specify `$character_set` parameter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php#69645) in oci_connect() call."

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails, you can http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php the string before inserting and decode after fetching. Worst case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all helps.
I cannot resolve this problem after all without recreate the database and reset the character set...
one thing I learned is that one MUST pay attention to the initial setting when creating a oracle database...